# Opening import file for module 'GoogleMaps': Not a file directory

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, compiler-errors

I'm experiencing this issue with Xcode 8.2.

I'm using Google Maps, but when I try to build for test, the build fails with this error:

`Opening import file for module 'GoogleMaps': Not a file directory`

I've update my pods, use_frameworks!, tried re-installing the pod, removed the cache, cleaned the project, and most all other relative suggestions regarding `:Not a file directory` issues.

Comment: did you add google maps inside test target in pod file?

Comment: Yes I did, pod 'GoogleMaps'

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37633766/no-such-module-googlemaps-found-however-it-is-installed

Comment: That solved the issue. Thank you Mr.Bista